# Listing files in a shared drive

Tags: perl

I have the path of a directory in a shared drive

`\\remote\dir` stored in a variable $path.

I need the list of all files in dir1. I used

```
my @files = glob($path."\\*");
```

@files is empty. I tried escaping the slashes in $path. This didn't work too. 
How do I get the list of files in `\\remote\dir` ?

I am on Windows.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't forget to escape the backslashes ? In sum there should be four backslashes in front of remote and two in front of dir because only half of them will make their way into the string. To be on the safe side you could print the value of $path to the screen, I bet you will see something strange

Comment: Works with slashes under win7; `perl -E "say for glob('//localhost/Users/*')"`

Comment: @Marged  OK I am embarrassed. I dont know what changed , I think i missed four backslashes... now it worked.. I simply did $path =~ s/\\/\\\\/g;    .... Thanks!!!! I thought I had tried that. Maybe you can add the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply will have to change your program this way:

```
my $path = "\\\\remote\\dir";
```

The reason for this is that perl will use the backslash as an escape character. If you want to have a backslash in a string you will have to escape the backslash by a second backslash.

Comment: Double the dashes for glob, then again or double-quotes, meaning you need 4x the slashes, so you need `"\\\\\\\\remote\\\\dir"` (to produce the glob pattern `\\\\remove\\dir`), which can be shortened to `"\\\\\\remote\\dir"` (which produces the glob pattern `\\\remote\dir`). What you posted doesn't work; it will looks in `\remote\dir` on the current drivee.

Comment: @ikegami you are correct, I didn't know about the "special" behavior of glob and just remembered that perl has the same "problem" with backslashes like C and Java. I suggest that someone create an answer which considers all of what was mentioned in thist post and that this one become the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

I find it easier to use forward slashes instead of escaping backslashes repeatedly:

```
my $path = "//dt01/users/steve";

my @files = glob($path."/desktop/*");

print "$_\n" for @files;
```

Output:

```
//dt01/users/steve/desktop/test.fil
//dt01/users/steve/desktop/desktop.ini
//dt01/users/steve/desktop/get-pip.py
//dt01/users/steve/desktop/install-tl-20150223
```

Comment: I think for perl this will work out always, but in general there is a certain "risk" when presenting forward slashes to Windows. I have seen situations where commands (admittedly outside of a perl program) failed because they were not run with backslashes